# MySql - Query Error: Error: ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

I have tbl which include 2 columns: title and params, the values are like the following:

```
- title: {"Teaching"}

- params:

{   "ufield926":"34",
    "ufield927":"Sud",
    "ufield928":"Ara",
    "ufield929":"Mecca",
    "ufield930":"1\/1\/1983",
    "ufield933":"011",
    "ufield934":"Mub",
    "ufield943":"SU\/HI\/14",
    "ufield944":"Average",
    "ufield946":"Female"
}
```

I want to extract the code after "`ufield943`": which is `SU/HI/14` only and concatenate it with the value in title column to be like the following:

```
--> Teaching (SU/HI/14)
```

Here is the query I have tried:

```
SELECT title, CONCAT(title, "(", (select *,
       substring(
         params,
         locate('ufield943', params) + 12,
         locate('ufield944', params) - locate('ufield943', params) - 15
       ) FROM tbl), ")") AS title
FROM tbl;
```

I get the following error everytime I run the query

> "Query Error: Error: ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

.

Comment: If you want just that then don’t use `*` in your select. Concat can’t concat rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql expects the exact field or value as `SELECT` statement fields. So, When you use an inner `SELECT` result as a field or value on outer `SELECT`, you have to return a specific value as a result.

So, You have to remove `*,` from your inner `SELECT` as the first step.

Another thing that you must do is removing `title` from outer `SELECT`. As your query `CONCAT` your title with the expected result, so there is no need of selecting `title` again.

So your query should like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(title, "(", (select 
       substring(
         params,
         locate('ufield943', params) + 12,
         locate('ufield944', params) - locate('ufield943', params) - 21
       ) FROM master_code), ")") AS title
FROM master_code;
```

As a final note, This is not a good approach to saving data as JSON in MySQL and accessing data like this.
Thanks to MySQL (5.7.8 or upper), you can use MySQL JSON type features or handle this using a programing language.

[**Demo**](https://rextester.com/MYKH68887)

Comment: Thanks I have tested the demo and the query work as intended, however, when run it on phpmyadmin I got the following error: 

#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row